# Texto aparece rápido

Tags: javascript, html

A pagina esta executando tudo certo, mas quando clico no menu ele exibe o texto muito rápido e depois apaga.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz o por que o texto desaparece apos o click?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

  var formacao = document.getElementById("formacao");
  var experiencia = document.getElementById("experiencia");
  var habilidade = document.getElementById("habilidade");
  var objetivo = document.getElementById("objetivo");

  objetivo.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let objeto = document.getElementById("menu")
    objeto.innerHTML = ("<h2>Objetivo</h2><p>Conseguir um emprego de estagio ou júnior na área de programador front-end.</p>")
  });
  formacao.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let objeto = document.getElementById("menu")
    objeto.innerHTML = ("<h2>Formação</h2><p>Graduação em Analise em Desenvolvimento de Sistemas. Previsão de termino: 2020/2</p>")
  });
  experiencia.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let objeto = document.getElementById("menu")
    objeto.innerHTML = ("<h2>Experiencia</h2><p><strong>Vennar Burger Empresário (Mei)</strong></p><p>Administração de uma pequena de empresa de hamburguer com 3 funcionários</p>")
  });
  habilidade.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let objeto = document.getElementById("menu")
    objeto.innerHTML = ("<h2>Habilidade</h2><ul><li>JavaScript</li><li>Html5</li><li>CSS3</li><li>Node</li><li>Postregresql</li><li>Mysql</li></ul>")
  });

  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Romulo Lessa Developer</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body onload="">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <!--Menu-->
      <ul>
        <li id="objetivo">
          <a href="">Objetivo</a>
        </li>
        <li id="formacao">
          <a href="">Formação</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Portifolio</a>
        </li>
        <li id="experiencia">
          <a href="">Experiencias</a>
        </li>
        <li id="habilidade">
          <a href="">Habilidades</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div id="menu"></div>

      <!--Conteudo Sobre min-->
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <!--Roda pe com contatos: github, linkedin, facebook, twitter, email-->
  </footer>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Caso o autor se incomode com a edição leia [Oh, não! Editaram minha pergunta!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2212/oh-n%c3%a3o-editaram-minha-pergunta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema acontece porque que ao clicar num item da lista, sua ancora `<a href="">` associada redireciona o navegador para uma página em branco(`about:blank`) logo após o conteúdo de `<div id="menu">` ser carregado via listener.

Uma forma de resolver é no próprio *HTML* fazendo com que a [ancora](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) não redirecione o browser usando a hashtag(`#`)

```
<a href="#">
```

Outra forma de resolver é em javascript usando o método [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) informando ao navegador que o evento `click` não precisa mais ser processado.

Dei uma simplificada no seu exemplo deixando apenas dois casos um usando `<a href="#">` e outro com `preventDefault()`:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

  let formacao = document.getElementById("formacao");
  let objetivo = document.getElementById("objetivo");

  let objeto = document.getElementById("menu")

  objetivo.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Aqui informa ao navegador que o evento não precisa mais ser processado.
    objeto.innerHTML = ("<h2>Objetivo</h2><p>Conseguir um emprego de estagio ou júnior na área de programador front-end.</p>")
  });

  formacao.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    objeto.innerHTML = ("<h2>Formação</h2><p>Graduação em Analise em Desenvolvimento de Sistemas. Previsão de termino: 2020/2</p>")
  });


  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Romulo Lessa Developer</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body onload="">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <!--Menu-->
      <ul>
        <li id="objetivo">
          <a href="">Objetivo</a>
        </li>
        <li id="formacao">
          <!-- O atributo href="#" previne que o link direcione a para about:blak-->
          <a href="#">Formação</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div id="menu"></div>

      <!--Conteudo Sobre min-->
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <!--Roda pé com contatos: github, linkedin, facebook, twitter, email-->
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber o que há de erado com essa resposta para receber um negativo?

Answer (score -1):

seja bem vindo ao stackOverFlow!

A charada que está passando despercebido pelos seus olhos é a seguinte:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {...
```

Mas por quê [RXSD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/127729/rxsd)?

Essa linha de comando adiciona um *Listener*, ou melhor, um ouvinte à sua página. É como se este trecho de código estivesse aguardando alguma função, no seu caso, o HTML ser totalmente executado [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), para poder ser ativada, que no seu caso não seria o interessante(uma vez que você quer tratar apenas o click de casa item do menu, certo?). Diante disso, nos deparamos com as seguintes situações:

1. O seu código irá passar por esse código JavaScript `sempre` que a página for renderizada, não sei se você percebeu, mas ao clicar em um item `<a>` sem URL de direcionamento `href=""` do menu, sua página está executando um *reload* passando novamente pelo que expliquei anteriormente.
2. Note que a tag `<a>` necessita de um `href`(este atributo especifica o URL da página para onde o link redirecionará, como você está utilizando o atributo vazio, a página está fazendo um refresh e consequentemente caindo na situação 1), porém, existem alguns macetes que você pode usar como por exemplo utilizar a cerquilha `#` como parâmetro do href, assim, você está dizendo ao navegador que seu link moverá o scroll da sua página para o topo, evitando o seu reload, [da uma olhadinha que tem um conteúdo bacana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855168/what-is-href-and-why-is-it-used).

Você pode utilizar seu código da seguinte forma:

```js
  document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var anchor = e.target.closest('a');
  if(anchor !== null) {
    var formacao = document.getElementById("formacao");
 var experiencia = document.getElementById("experiencia");
 var habilidade = document.getElementById("habilidade");
 var objetivo = document.getElementById("objetivo");

   objetivo.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let menu= document.getElementById("menu")
  menu.innerHTML = ("<h2>Objetivo</h2><p>Conseguir um emprego de estagio ou júnior na área de programador front-end.</p>")
   });
   formacao.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let menu= document.getElementById("menu")
  menu.innerHTML = ("<h2>Formação</h2><p>Graduação em Analise em Desenvolvimento de Sistemas. Previsão de termino: 2020/2</p>")
   });
   experiencia.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let menu= document.getElementById("menu")
  menu.innerHTML = ("<h2>Experiencia</h2><p><strong>Vennar Burger Empresário (Mei)</strong></p><p>Administração de uma pequena de empresa de hamburguer com 3 funcionários</p>")
   });
   habilidade.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let menu= document.getElementById("menu")
  menu.innerHTML = ("<h2>Habilidade</h2><ul><li>JavaScript</li><li>Html5</li><li>CSS3</li><li>Node</li><li>Postregresql</li><li>Mysql</li></ul>")
   });

   console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
  }
}, false);
```

```html
  <header>
    <nav>
      <!--Menu-->
      <ul>
        <li id="objetivo">
          <a href="#">Objetivo</a>
        </li>
        <li id="formacao">
          <a href="#">Formação</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Portifolio</a>
        </li>
        <li id="experiencia">
          <a href="#">Experiencias</a>
        </li>
        <li id="habilidade">
          <a href="#">Habilidades</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div id="menu"></div>

      <!--Conteudo Sobre min-->
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <!--Roda pe com contatos: github, linkedin, facebook, twitter, email-->
  </footer>
```

Repare que agora, não estamos adicionando um `Listener` para sempre que houver um load/reload da página, agora estamos **aguardando apenas click** de um dos itens ancorados `<a>`.

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('click', function(e) {...
```

Lembra que os href's estão utilizando a `#` apenas para evitar a recarga da página.

E não esquece de tratar o item **• Portifolio** ein?!

Comment: Essa resposta esta equivocada, [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)  e acionado uma vez quando  o documento HTML inicial foi completamente carregado e analisado, sem aguardar folhas de estilo, imagens e sub-quadros para concluir o carregamento. Ou seja após a arvore DOM ser construída e disponibilizada e não tem nada haver com reloads. A instalação de observadores de eventos dentro desse evento `DOMContentLoaded` visa salvaguardar a instalação de listeners de outros scripts efetuando alterações dinâmicas no DOM durante a carga...

Comment: ... outra coisa, da forma que esta fazendo, a cada clique esta desnecessariamente reinstalando todos o observadores de evento. Para verificar é simples na primeira linha de seu callback para `body` coloque alert("xxxxxxxx"); e qualquer clique de der nos links ou em qualquer ouro lugar da página o alerta aparecerá indicando que a cada clique todos o listeners estão sendo re-registrado.

Comment: Você está dizendo que o DomContentLoaded é acionado só uma vez, diante da maneira que está implementado pelo Romulo?  Para isso é muito simples, basta adicionar um breakpoint no seu JavaScript, você verá que o código irá cair lá 1x, no load da página. 2x no click do item, 3x no reload da página. Você consegue entender o que eu me refiro com reload?

Comment: Mas esse é comportamento default, uma chamada do evento para uma carga do DOM. O único erro que ele cometeu foi apontar os links para about:blank para consertar basta fazer '<a href="#">' em todos os links

Comment: No seu caso a cada clique todos os listeners são reinstalados , tanto que a linha `console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');` é evocada persistentemente a cada clique.

Comment: Cara o console está sendo chamado apenas nos clicks dos itens do menu...

Comment: Se isso acontece é porque todo o código que acompanha essa chamada também está sendo executado(reinstalação dos listeners).

Comment: Você pode demonstrar essa afirmação " *tanto que a linha console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed'); é evocada persistentemente a cada clique.* " de maneira visual?

Comment: Você já está em loop é só criar um contador https://imgur.com/a/sRgVMWL

Comment: ou então execute o seu código no sandbox e pressione por varias vezes qualquer um dos itens até a tela ser coberta pela frase `DOM fully loaded and parsed`

Comment: Tem mais outro erro que percebi agora, a primeira vez que clica em qualquer um dos itens o `menu.innerHTML` não é preenchido só é preenchido do segundo clique em diante.